# Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax

Tags: reactjs, excel, download, vite

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hM8RX.png)[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. You may need to install appropriate plugins to handle the .xlsx file format, or if it's an asset, add "**/*.xlsx" to `assetsInclude` in your configuration.

"I tried changing the Vite configuration, but not much has changed."